# Menu to the right of screen on desktop using Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I'm fairly new to WordPress development and would love to learn as much as possible. I am building a theme from scratch and using the wp-bootstrap-navwalker (https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker) as the fallback for my display.

Here is what I currently have:
[image]

How do I move the menu choices to the right of the screen with affecting the mobile version as shown below?
[image]

I would like to keep the mobile version the same, but just have the desktop version move to the right - I've tried applying different attributes that make it go to the right, but then the mobile version doesn't work.

Here is the code:
header.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
<div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-controls="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location'  => 'header-menu',
                'depth'           => 2, // 1 = no dropdowns, 2 = with dropdowns.
                'container'       => 'div',
                'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'    => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
                'fallback_cb'     => 'WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'          => new WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
            ) );
        ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Bootstrap class [justify-content-end](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) on the `<div>` that holds the menu (that with the class `navbar-collapse`). Check the next sample:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md bg-primary">

  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-end">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Staff</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Specialty Area</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Research Tools</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">More</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to make it workout:

```css
.navbar-collapse > ul {
    margin-left: auto!important;
}
```

Comment: Even if this works good, I recommend to avoid the overwrite of the Bootstrap classes style and the usage of `!important`. Bootstrap 4 already have utility classes for justify content horizontally. Check my answer if you want to know how to do it with Bootstrap.